# Nested Structure Syntax

Tags: c

I have a quick question..is there any difference in these:

```
struct myinnerstruct
{
    int x;

};

struct mystruct
{
    struct myinnerstruct m;
    int y;
};
```

AND THIS

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    struct myinnerstruct
    {
        int y;
    };
    struct myinnerstruct m; 
};
```

These both work as far as I can tell, but I'm wondering if there's a reason to pick one or the other.  Thanks

Comment: Is the second variant even legal C?

Comment: I haven't really been able to find any examples of it online.  My tests for both return the same results.  So AFAIK, it is.

Comment: The following would also work, to make the second one a bit shorter: `struct mystruct { int x; struct myinnerstruct { int y; } m; };` IMHO, the best reason to define a `struct` inside another `struct` is when the inner `struct` is used exclusively and perhaps repeatedly as a member of the outer `struct`, i.e. when a `struct` has to have many "groups" storing similar information for different purposes.

Comment: @prelic: GCC throws a warning...

Comment: @Oli - If the OP combines the `struct` definition and member declaration into one line, then yes.

Comment: Chris Thanks for the tip.  However, both solutions allow declaration of the inner struct independent of the outer, so that's confusing.  EDIT: @Oli That's true but Chris' tip makes that warning go away.  I only did it that way because I was trying to be verbose.

Comment: It does look like `myinnerstruct` shouldn't be accessable outside of `mystruct` (or like it should be `mystruct::myinnerstruct` as it would be in C++), but that's just how the C++ language works. The usual usage of this is with anonymous `struct`s, so that it's never an issue that the `struct` name exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the second one is invalid.

The stuff between the `{` and `}` in a struct declaration is a sequence of member declarations.  Your

```
    struct myinnerstruct
    {
        int y;
    };
```

is a type declaration; it doesn't declare a member of the enclosing struct, so it's illegal in that context.

What you *can* do is this:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    struct myinnerstruct
    {
        int y;
    } m;
};
```

The declaration of `m` is a member declaration, so it's ok; it also declares the type `struct myinnerstruct`.  But in my opinion, it's poor style.  The type `struct myinnerstruct` remains visible after the declaration of `struct mystruct` is completed; see below for the explanation.

If you really want a struct within a struct like that, and you're not going to use `struct myinnerstruct` anywhere else, you could leave it without a tag:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    struct
    {
        int y;
    } m;
};
```

But then you might as well declare `y` as a member of `struct mystruct`.

If you want `struct innerstruct` to be a named type, just declare it separately, as you did in your first example.

Here's the explanation of *why* `struct innerstruct` remains visible.

The [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (large PDF), section 6.2.1 paragraph 2, says:

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the
>   identifier is *visible* (i.e., can be used) only within a region of
>   program text called its *scope*.  Different entities designated by the
>   same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name
>   spaces.  There are four kinds of scopes: function, file, block, and
>   function prototype.  (A *function prototype* is a declaration of a
>   function that declares the types of its parameters.)

The C90 and C11 standards have essentially the same wording.

The `{` braces `}` in a struct declaration do not define a block, nor do they define any of the other possible kinds of scope, so anything declared between the braces is not scoped to that region; it must be scoped to some surrounding context.  It happens that the syntax lets you declare `struct myinnerstruct` inside another struct definition -- but only if it's part of a member definition.  I think this is allowed only because the designers of the language didn't go to any extra effort to disallow it; it's just a side effect of other rules.  You *can* do it, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: So if I wanted to have a [inner] struct which couldn't be declared on its own (but only by declaring with an outer struct), I should nest the definitions but leave the inner one without a tag, as in your example?

Comment: @prelic: It depends.  Why do you want an inner struct in the first place?  In the (presumably) simplified code you've shown us, there's only one instance of `struct innerstruct`, and it's a member of `struct mystruct`.  Why not flatten the structure, so that the members of `struct innerstruct` become direct members of `struct mystruct`?  I'm not necessarily saying that that's the right solution, but knowing why it isn't (if it isn't) would help in determining how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Yeah I realize in this example, it's trivial to flatten my structure.  But where I'm actually applying this, it's not as clear cut.  I work with (reasonably) large structures, and these structures make up bigger structures.  It's significant whether or not the component structures are visible outside of the set of structures.

Comment: Well, you can't actually hide a structure type inside another one, unless you leave it without a tag.  If it needs a tag, I'd declare it outside the containing structure, which more clearly shows the actual visibility.

Answer (score 1):

A reason to choose one or the other would be conventional expectations.

A structure declaration nested within another would not be expected to be reused elsewhere, even though it can be.

Also, there is a psychological clash by not putting things of the same level of abstraction side-by-side.  It is perfectly legal to do it, but it makes understanding the code a little harder and maybe more irritating.